# Access to the camera

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ios

To check the availability of the flag to the camera, I use
Camera.isSupported ( in packagerforiphone_devguide.pdf 29 page)
But on the iphone always returns false.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Flash packager for the iPhone (which, by your tags, it seems like you are), you don't have access to many of the native features on the iPhone including the camera. (or RTMPE streams, pixelbender filters, microphone access, etc). Read up on it all here: http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Applications_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ